# One call works but not the other (same) w AssetLibrary / UIImage

Tags: uiview, alassetslibrary, custom-cell

Got an UIIMagePickerController in my "newPlayerVC" that saves an thumbnail image (after I  resized it down to 100x100 px) to the AssetLibrary without any problems.

Dirrectly after saving the image I put in another call to the AssetLibrary again to fetch the just saved image to show the user (and also check that it works ok). That call looks like this;

```
// Display new thumbnail via AssetLIbrary call
    __block UIImage *_image = nil;
    [assetLib assetForURL:(playerImageURL)
              resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                  _image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];
                  NSLog(@"Got the asset thumbnail, %@",_image);
                  [playerImageButton setImage:_image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              }

             failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Asset (image) fetch failed because %@",error);
             }];
```

**So far it works just fine.** 
The terminal confirm logs with: "p.playerImage = assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=A79242D5-BC91-490B-BC37-0A9F529675EE&ext=JPG" and "Got the asset thumbnail, UIImage: 0xcb5b8a0" - so I know it's getting the image from the asset library.

But then I try to do a very simular call from my "playerTableVC" to populate a tableview with that earlier saved image to an UIView in my custom cell - it just dont work (the custom cell is ok and wok with static images). Also I get no errors or warnings either from Xcode. That code looks like this from the function "- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath";

```
// Set up Asset library
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];

__block UIImage *_image = nil;
[assetLib assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p.playerImage]
          resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
              _image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullResolutionImage]];
              NSLog(@"Got the asset thumbnail, %@", _image);
          }

 failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Asset fetch failed: %@",error);
 }];

// If no cell, create new
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CellPlayer alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

// If cell present, assign values
NSLog(@"p.playerImage = %@", p.playerImage);  // Check = ok

// Check if imageurl is empty = default image else the user choosen image
if ([p.playerImage isEqualToString:@""]) {
    cell.cellPlayerIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultImageFrame_114x114"];
    // Add sortingorder ("player position") to tableview
    cell.cellPlayerStarIcon.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (indexPath.row +1)];
} else {
    cell.cellPlayerIcon.image = _image;  // = NO IMAGE IN CELL?
    // Add sortingorder ("player position") to tableview
    cell.cellPlayerStarIcon.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.", (indexPath.row +1)];
}

cell.cellPlayerName.text = p.playerName;
cell.cellPlayerTime.text = p.playerTime;
cell.cellPlayerTimestamp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", p.playerTimeStamp];  // @"2012-10-01 @ 8:06";

return cell;
```

}

I belive I doing something wrong with the setting of the UIIMage in populating the cell above. Everything else works ok an also with a static UIImage. Tried a lot of variations of this and believe I know finally gone "code-flind"... ;-)

Got any solutions, tips, pointers etc? Thanks :-)

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

Turns out that the block did not retain the image in the above "_image"-variable. Simply solved with passing "_image" to a local variable like UIImage "myImage" within the block to retain it. It now works just fine and my cells get their images from the asset library as expected :-)